# how to store and prefilled data using React Native Material Ui stepper?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a project in react native and i am getting issue. I have submitted details using @material.ui/react-native-stepper library. I want a copy functionality on copy button, but i am unable to show all the stepper steps prefilled, so that user just have to enter the last step detail and rest details gets filled automatically (Copy Case).

```
<StepperContainer>
  <StepView title='Intro' subTitle='The intro details'>
    <Text>Step 1 Contents</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Second' onNext={() => true} subTitle='Name and other details'>
    <Text>Step 2 Contents</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Third Step' subTitle='Some lines'>
    <Text>Step 3 Contents …!</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Last Step' subTitle='Finishing lines'>
    <Text>Step 4 Contents …!</Text>
  </StepView>
</StepperContainer>
```

I just want if user copies the above filled details on click of copy button next time so he doesn't need to enter full details again but just enter the last step detail.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no prop expose for this, you can copy the code from the library can create your own Stepper.

Comment: This library do provide this feature `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stepper-ui`